# Why the button in old fragment still working when add the new fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing in Android. There are two fragment in an **Activity**. The **fragment-A** has a Button , and the **Activity** will show the **fragment-A** first.

I use the following code to add the **fragment-B**.

```
SecondFragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment ();
mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.container, secondFragment )
                            .addToBackStack(secondFragment .getClass().getName()).commit();
```

But the `OnClickListener` of `button` in **fragment-A** is still working when I touch the position of button after the view already change to the **fragment-B**.

Did I missing something ? How to solve the problem if I do not use `replace` or `setClickble to false`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: set your Fragment - B parent layout clickable=true and focusable=true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens due to the transparency of events in fragments.

You could add the below attributes to the root view group of the second fragment to avoid passing click event to backstacked fragments

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Comment: Thanks! I also add the focusable = true